# junit.Framework.AssertionFailedError trying to Read From a File to a ArrayList

Tags: java, file, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have to read from a file and then place the words that are found into a ArrayList.

```
public boolean load(String filename)
{

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("wordlist.txt")));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] values = line.split("\n");
            wordlist.add(new WordPair(answer, question));
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioe);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Below is the tester code I have used:

```
public void testLoad() {
    assertTrue(wordPairDemo.save(fileName));    
    wordPairDemo.clear();                       
    assertTrue(wordPairDemo.load(fileName));
    assertTrue(wordPairDemo.size() == 3);
    assertEquals(wordPairDemo.lookup("hest"),"horse");
    assertEquals(wordPairDemo.lookup("hus"), "house");
    assertEquals(wordPairDemo.lookup("båd"),"boat");
}
```

I get the junit.Framework.AssertionFailedError, and I am not sure what is causing it. I have tried several different types of ways of doing this, through scanners, etc. but I always get this error, and I am not sure what to do with it.

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your example in the comment below, the file contains pairs in single line:
`horse,hesthouse,husboat,båd`

you should split according to the actual delimiter you're using - `,`.
E.g.:

```
public boolean load(String filename)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("wordlist.txt")));
        String line = null;

        // I'm leaving this loop under the assumption that there may be multiple lines
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < line.lenght() / 2; ++i) {
                wordlist.add(new WordPair(values[i], values[i + 1));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioe);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The words in the file aren't seperated by anything when they are added, so there are no spaces between, so I guess that's a cause of how they're added to the text file. Would I be correct in this assupmtion?

I trie ading the [0] and [1] but it gives me the error: "array required, but found string'.

Comment: can you share an example of your text file?

Comment: horse,hesthouse,husboat,båd 

is what it looks like when the 3 word pairs are added into the word file

Comment: fixed my answer according to newer info. @MadsRosenmeyer consider also adding this info to the question - it would make it clearer for everyone attempting to help you.

Comment: Ye, sorry, I'm still not quite sure what is meant to be placed in the Question to allow for all you guys to easier answer the question. :)

Comment: Right, so I added your new code to my program, but I get the error '4', which I guess has, once again, something to do with the formatting and how it reads from the file.